# Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate fails to connect to MySql

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2010, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have two database. One in **Access 2007** and another remote in **MySQL**. The Access 2007 has to update the MySQL database. In Visual Studio there is tool under `Data-->New Data Comparison` which seems to compare the databases and synchronize them.

I have two challenges:

1. Connect to MySQL database. It defaults to `port 3306` and this is not the port I want.
   How do I change the that port to 3307 ?
2. How to make this database show on Data Comparison so that I can compare my two databases i.e access 2007 and MySQL.

Comment: I have  seen where you can change port. After clicking Advanced  under Connection, change from port 3306 to whatevet port you are using.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your first Question:

You can change the port number to `3307`from `my.cnf` file.

`Stop MySQL [3306] -> modify my.cnf ->Start MySQL [3307].`.

Comment: Where is the my.cnf file? I am using Visual Studio 2010. Its for interest sake as I have manage with the first question. See my comment above.